# Dynamically add a row to a table which is already present in html in C#

Tags: html, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a table in my .aspx page as follows.

```
<table id="Test_Table">

</table>
```

I need to add a row dynamically in my .cs page for the above table:

I tried the following which I found.

I created a button on its onclick() I wrote the following code.

```
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        cell1.Text = "Sample Text";
        row.Cells.Add(cell1);
        Test_Table.Rows.Add(row);
```

But this is not working. It says that the table does not exist in the current context.
Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **html**-table:

```
<table id="Test_Table">
```

You should add `runat="server"`, then you can access it from serverside. But if you need to create rows dynamically you should use an ASP.NET [`Table` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the first place.

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="Test_Table">
</asp:Table>
```

Now you can access it via `Id` and [`Rows`-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
// ...
Test_Table.Rows.Add(row);
```

However, note that it's not that simple to add controls dynamically in ASP.NET. They will be dosposed at the end of the page's current liefcycle, so as soon as the html was rendered   and sent to the client. You need to recreate it on every postback in `Page_Load`(at the latest) with the same ID (if any) as before.

Therefore you need to persist how many rows you have already added, you could use a `ViewState` or `Session` variable.

Comment: @user2439093: have you noticed that i've edited my answer to provide further informations?

Comment: Yes I did. Thank You to provide the further information.